# Как использовать API Token Gismeteo?

Tags: android, android-studio, api, kotlin

До сегодняшнего момента не работал с api и у меня появился вопрос по поводу использования токена. Как установить соединение с сервером и куда вставлять этот токен? Работаю на Kotlin под Android Studio.

Прикладываю код:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val myAsync = MyAsync()
    myAsync.execute()

}
}

class MyAsync: AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
val url = URL("https://gismeteo.ru/")
val conn = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {

    conn.requestMethod = "POST"
    conn.doInput = true
    conn.doOutput = true
    conn.connect()

    val sb = StringBuilder()

    val bufferReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(conn.inputStream, "UTF-8"))

    var line = bufferReader.readLine()

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line)
        Log.d("!", line)
        line = bufferReader.readLine()
    }


    return null
}

override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
    super.onPostExecute(result)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нужен собственно пример запроса который требует API Gismeteo.

Но обычно токен вставляется в параметры запроса как параметр
Например:

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/account?api_key=your_api_key

Если токен отправляется в каждом запросе и вы используете Retrofit, то вполне можно написать интерсептор.

Здесь вы можете посмотреть как это делается:
https://medium.com/knowing-android/headers-interceptors-and-authenticators-with-retrofit-1a00fed0d5eb